# How to manipulate a parameter in mySQL according to server time

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-mvc

i have built a RESTful server with a database with Spring/hibernate/mySQL.

i have a table of a bank savings account that has 3 savings balance columns.

for example:

```
account_id | a_savings | b_savings | c_savings  
1          | 100       | 200       | 300
```

i want that each day (or month) , each savings account will add 0.01%(or other amount) to its value automatically according to the server/current time.

how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it with scheduling tasks:

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

@Autowired
private SavingsAccountDao savingsAccountDao;

/* each day at 8 am */
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 8 * * *")
public void increaseSavingsAccount() {
    log.info("Savings Accounts Updated", dateFormat.format(new Date()));

    /* get all savings accounts and increase balance according to the interest */
    List<SavingsAccount> savingsAccountList = savingsAccountDao.findAll();
    savingsAccountList.forEach((sa) -> {

        /* 39% interest in 12 months */
        sa.setASavingsBalance(sa.getASavingsBalance().multiply(new BigDecimal(1.0009)));
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Write a method that pauses for an amount of time than call a method that

1. load the current value of a field by SQL
2. increase the values of a field by calculating its value, `value = value+(value*0.01)` then use SQL to update the value.

For pause in java use `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(2);` of `java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit` here `2` stands for `2 Minutes` . You can also use DAYS/HOURS `TimeUnit.DAYS.sleep(1);`